# How to get a term before a character?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to get the number before 'x'?

I tried using `.split('x')[0]` but it grabs everything before 'x'.

```
123x // Gives 123
123y+123x - // Gives 123
123x+123x - // Gives 246
```

Comment: What would be the output of `"-1x*200x"`, `"10x+30x*2x"`??

Comment: What is expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested a function which uses regex that I think will work.  I've included the results, an explanation of how the function works, and then a commented version of the function.

Note, this doesn't handle any algebra more complex than adding and subtracting simple terms. I would refer to https://newton.now.sh/ for that, it's an API which can handle simplification (I am not affiliated).

Results:

```
console.log(coefficient("-x+23x"));     // 22
console.log(coefficient("123y+123x"));  // 123
// replaces spaces
console.log(coefficient("x + 123x"));   // 124
console.log(coefficient("-x - 123x"));  // -124
console.log(coefficient("1234x-23x"));  // 1211
// doesn't account for other letters
console.log(coefficient("-23yx"));      // 1
```

Explanation:

First the function removes spaces. Then it uses a regex, which finds any sequence of numbers that are followed by an 'x'. If there's a +/- in front, the regex keeps that. The function loops through these sequences of numbers, and adds them to a total. If there's an 'x' that does not have numbers with it, its coefficient is assumed as -1 or 1.

Commented Code:

```
function coefficient(str) {
  // remove spaces
  str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');

  // all powerful regex
  var regexp = /(\+|-)?[0-9]*x/g

  // total
  sum = 0;

  // find the occurrences of x
  var found = true;
  while (found) {
    match = regexp.exec(str);
    if (match == null) {
      found = false;
    } else {
      // treated as +/- 1 if no proceeding number
      if (isNaN(parseInt(match[0]))) {
        if (match[0].charAt(0) == "-") {
          sum--;
        } else {
          sum++;
        }
      // parse the proceeding number
      } else {
        sum += parseInt(match[0]);
      }
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(match('123x+123y+456x', 'x'))
console.log(match('123x+123y+456x', 'y'))

function match(str, x) {
  return str.match(new RegExp('\\d+' + x, 'g')).reduce((cur, p) => {
    return cur + parseInt(p.substr(0, p.length - x.length))
  }, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is sufficient cleverness in ECMAScript regular expressions to do look behind, but you can do it with *match* and post processing to remove the "x".

If the intention is to sum the terms, then a further operation with *reduce* is required. Trimming the x could be combined with reduce so that *map* isn't required.

```js
console.log(
  '123x+123x'.match(/\d+x/ig).map(function(v){
    return v.slice(0,-1)
  }).reduce(function(sum, v){return sum + +v},0)
);
```